# npm ERR when I typed npm command "vue create vue-login-sign-ui"

Tags: vue.js, npm

I tryed to create login page using Vue so that I typed npm command in my terminal like "vue create vue-login-sign-ui"
At first npm seem to work properly but after a while npm error log appeared

[image]

I try to find answer in stack overflow and solve this problem.
So I typed "npm cache clean --force" but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@vue/cli` is overall not maintained anymore: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli

Please use [`create-vue`](https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue) with `npm create vue@latest`

---

Please also double check that you're using the current LTS of Node + your firewall/network is properly setup and open.
If you still have some issues, it may be a Windows issue. Please try it in a WSL shell.